# Limit of Hankel function for large complex order, fixed real argument

Tags: cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions

Consider the Hankel function $H_\nu(z)$ where $\nu=re^{i\theta}$ (real $z>0$, $r>0$, $0\leq\theta<\pi$) as $r\rightarrow\infty$. I am aware that the Bessel function $J_\nu(z)$ has the following dependence, obtained from its series definition:

$$ J_\nu(z)\rightarrow  \frac{(z/2)^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}(1+\mathcal{O}(\nu^{-1})) $$

and that the Hankel function can be obtained from

$$ H_\nu(z)=\frac{J_{-\nu}(z)-e^{-i\pi\nu}J_\nu(z)}{i\sin(\pi\nu)} \qquad \theta\neq 0.$$

But the limit of $J_\nu(z)$ depends on $\theta$ :

for $r\rightarrow\infty, \theta\rightarrow0$, we have $J_{-\nu}>>J_\nu$,

for $r\rightarrow\infty, \theta\rightarrow \pi/2$, we have $J_\nu>>J_{-\nu}$.

This paper
[HIGH FREQUENCY SCATTERING BY AN IMPENETRABLE SPHERE, W. E. I. Sha and W. C. Chew, 2009] mentions an anti-Stokes line at $\theta=\pi/3$, which I believe means there is a drastic shift in the limit for $\theta$ either side of these lines. But the paper does not cite where this comes from.

Numerically it seems for $\pi/3<\theta<\pi/2$, that

$$H_\nu(z)\rightarrow 2J_\nu(z)\rightarrow \frac{2(z/2)^\nu}{\Gamma(\nu+1)}.$$

Is this true analytically?

Comment: Did you look at [the DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.20#ii)? The asymptotic is given explicitly, and the limit $\theta=\pi/3$ is discussed.